# Android gl no current context

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es

I am trying to load some shaders and render a hello world triangle with an android GLSurfaceView and C++ using the official NDK. However I get the error "call to OpenGL ES API with no current context". Here is my simple single file java (note this is the only java code in the entire project) side context creation code from [google's tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/environment.html):

```
class GLESRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer
{
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("native_code");
    }
    private native void ntInit();
    private native void ntRender();
    private native void ntUpdateScreen(int width, int height);

    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 unused, EGLConfig config) {
        ntInit(); // LOAD SHADERS AND VBO DATA!!!!
    }

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {
        ntRender(); // DRAW USING SHADERS AND VBO DATA!!!!
    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 unused, int width, int height) {
        ntUpdateScreen(width, height); // UPDATE SCREEN!!!
    }
}

class GLES_SurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {

    private final GLESRenderer mRenderer;

    public GLES_SurfaceView(Context context){
        super(context);
        setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        mRenderer = new GLESRenderer();
        setRenderer(mRenderer);
    }
}

public class Main extends Activity {

    private GLSurfaceView mGLView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mGLView = new GLES_SurfaceView(this);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        } else {
            View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);

            ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
            if(bar != null)
                bar.hide();
        }
        setContentView(mGLView);
    }
}
```

Many other stack overflow questions (none of which use the NDK, so they are probably different problems) suggest that this is a threading issue, but this code clearly calls the native functions from the GLSurfaceView.Renderer, so I am pretty sure this is not a thread issue.

Furthermore, multiple tutorials use this same approach for rendering using opengl and the NDK. For example: [Intel's tutorial](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/setting-up-native-opengl-es-on-android-platforms), and [learnopengles's tutorial](http://www.learnopengles.com/calling-opengl-from-android-using-the-ndk/).

Thus I think there is something wrong in my context creation

Comment: If you are going to downvote my post, why don't you leave some feedback on how I can improve my question? I have clearly thoroughly researched this topic to the best of my ability. Do not be a douche-bag.

Comment: Did you confirm that the error is from your code? I think these error messages sometimes show up in logs without any connection to calls you make, and can be harmless. To narrow down the problem, I would set the clear color to something other than black, and put a `glClear()` call in the Java code. This will confirm that the context creation worked.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Yes I have ran glClear with different glClearColors in the ndk-side of my project and it ran perfectly! So maybe you are right and it was just a useless error and my problem lies elsewhere. Thank you for the tip, il investigate other parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to answer this question. This problem occurred because of C++'s default constructor system. Before my OpenGL context was created, I was loading my "native_code" library. My native shader classes however had default constructors which made OpenGL calls to initialize themselves. Something like this:

```
class LightingShader
{
    LightingShader()
    {
        glCreateShader(...) // BAD TO CALL OPENGL HERE WITHOUT CONTEXT CREATED
        ....
    }
};

....
LightingShader light_shader; // <- GLOBAL VARIABLE, DEFAULT CONSTRUCTOR CALLED!!!!
```

So basically when they library was loaded, the C++ shaders were automatically getting their constructors called. And this library was called before OpenGL was initialized! I fixed this by removing the default constructor and instead using a function which returned the object instead:

```
class LightingShader
{
    LightingShader getLightingShaderInstance()
    {
        glCreateShader(...)
        ....
    }
};
```

Thus it was a sneaky bug hidden in bad object oriented design on my part.